# failing to run edgetpu detect on coral dev board

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-coral

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RpNI4ZrfIM, I downloaded the labels and tflite model and moved them to `/all_models`, when I tried running

`edgetpu_detect_server --model ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --labels coco_labels.txt`

it returned the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/edgetpu_detect_server", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('edgetpuvision==7.0', 'console_scripts', 'edgetpu_detect_server')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect_server.py", line 33, in main
    run_server(add_render_gen_args, render_gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/apps.py", line 43, in run_server
    camera = make_camera(args.source, next(gen), args.loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect.py", line 133, in render_gen
    labels = utils.load_labels(args.labels) if args.labels else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 28, in load_labels
    return {int(num): text.strip() for num, text in lines}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 28, in <dictcomp>
    return {int(num): text.strip() for num, text in lines}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    lines = (LABEL_PATTERN.match(line).groups() for line in f.readlines())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I've already installed the following before trying to run the model:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tflite-runtime
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

any pointers as to what I should do? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to follow the updated documentation from https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#run-demo.

Comment: @jeb2 its most probably late to answer but just give number before the class: like 1 car \n 2 person... etc.  in coco_labels.txt  (I faced the same issue and solved like that)